# use dfs does not work in later versions of drill on the drill web page

Tags: sql, apache-drill

When using the web page displayed by drill on localhost:8047/query (by default) running the following commands fail:

```
use dfs.mydfs;
```

and then:

```
show files;
```

Then I receive this error:

```
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION ERROR: SHOW FILES is supported in workspace type schema only. Schema [] is not a workspace schema. [Error Id: 872e6708-0aaa-480e-af32-9aaf6f84de2b on 172.28.128.1:31010]
```

While if I use the terminal to enter the same commands the command works correct.

I've also found that this affects 1.6 and above and that this behaviour is not seen on 1.5 below.

This command works in both the web and commmand line/terminal version:

```
show files in df.workspace;
```

I have configured multiple types of dfs and have tried both OS X and Windows 10 and found the issue to be the same.

I tried looking through the drill jira to see if this was registered as bug and I looked briefly through the release notes as well.